# directory is not empty error

Tags: batch-file

I try in my batch file o delete folder(BR) with many files and subdirectories, I try the following:

**if exist C:\BR (
rmdir "C:\BR" /S /q 
)**

but sometimes I get an error that a specific folder is not empty.these folder contains files of CSS.
what the problem??

Comment: Odds are one or more files/directories are still in use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
rd /s /q DIRNAME
rmdir /s /q DIRNAME
```

The files that you can't delete are in use.
Close whatever program is holding them open, probably your browser, and try again.

Let me guess, your trying to delete your `%TMP%` folder.

---

---

**EDIT:** To answer zipi's question.

It will delete every file and folder that it can.  So, if `c:\tmp\dir2\dir3\open.txt` is open, `c:\tmp\emptyDir` is an empty directory, and you do this:

```
c:\>dir c:\tmp /b /s
c:\tmp\a.txt
c:\tmp\dir2\b.txt
c:\tmp\dir2\dir3\open.txt

c:\>rd /q /s c:\tmp

c:\>dir /s /b c:\tmp
c:\tmp\dir2\dir3\open.txt
```

You will have deleted:

```
c:\tmp\a.txt
c:\tmp\dir2\b.txt
```

And removed:

```
c:\tmp\emptyDir
```

But still have the directories...

```
c:\tmp
c:\tmp\dir2
c:\tmp\dir2\dir3
```

...an the file:

```
c:\tmp\dir2\dir3\open.txt
```

If instead, `a.txt` was open, you'd only have:

```
c:\tmp\
```

and

```
c:\tmp\a.txt
```

Comment: yes I think that this is the problem.but if these error appear it means that the folder don't delete?or only the message appear and the folder deleting well?

Comment: @zipi - It will delete and remove everything it can, and leave only those files (and the folders in their path) undeleted and unremoved. I've added to the answer if you need a visual for this.

Comment: Hi JAMES!THE PROBLEM REPRODUCE ALSO IF THERE ARE NO FOLDERS THAT OPEN  ..DO YOU KNOW WHY???

Comment: @zipi - It could be that you're current directory is in one of the directories you are trying to remove.

Comment: @zipi - The open file might be hidden. Type `dir /a:h /b /s` to see them. You ***may** need to unhide them before you can delete them. Use the `attrib` command like this `attrib -h c:\path\to\file.ext` or `attrib -h %tmp%\*.* /s` to unhide all hidden files in your %tmp% folder and all it's subdirectories.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. Tried lots of different solutions, but ultimately only the following worked:

```
rmdir c:\<directory> /s /q
```

Previously using other methods in CMD I was getting the following:

> The directory is not empty.

Answer (score 2):

On win7 I use a simple bat file to go around the problem:

```
call :rmdir "my_directory_01"
call :rmdir "my_directory_02"
pause
goto :EOF

:rmdir
  if exist %1 rmdir /s /q %1
  if exist %1 goto :rmdir
goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the solution is very silly. Please use /Q first and the /S to resolve your issue. so command should be something like:

IF EXIST %build_folder% RD /Q /S %build_folder%

Please let me know if this solves your issue.

Regards
Anuj

Answer (score 0):

To remove directory in command line, you have to remove all of files and subsolders it cointainst at the first place. The problem may occur if some of those items are read-only. /f will try to force delete them.

Try

```
if exists C:\BR (del "C:\BR" /f /s /q)
```

Here you have MS docs of the DEL command: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/del.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Actually, `rmdir /s /q` removes read-only files forcefully, there is no need for the `del` command beforehand. The problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

you will need to go to any drive where the folder is. Then right click on drive > properties > Check Scan disk or scan drive and for windows8 scan and repair

then go back to your folder and delete it

[Batch - Getting "The directory is not empty" on rmdir command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948189/batch-getting-the-directory-is-not-empty-on-rmdir-command/23293219#23293219)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the failure to remove a directory using rd /Q /S and getting Directory not empty was down to file permissions. The batch job was doing a backup and removing oldest backup folder at the end to keep latest 10 backups. The normal user account only had read and execute permission on certain files in the sub folders. Running the batch file containing the rd commands under Task Scheduler with a tick in the option "run with highest privileges" enabled directory's to be removed.

You could achieve something similar as a one off if you run your batch file under cmd and choose run as administrator. In Windows 7 type CMD in the Search programs and files box, then right click on cmd.exe at the top of the popup window and click Run as Administrator. Then find and run your batch file in the cmd "black background" window.