# How to solve "The directory is not empty" error when running rmdir command in a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am making a batch script and part of the script is trying to remove a directory and all of its sub-directories. I am getting an intermittent error about a sub-directory not being empty. I read one article about indexing being the culprit. I disabled WSearch but I eventually got the error again. Here's the command:

```
rmdir /S /Q "C:\<dir>\"
```

Comment: Can I ask some info about the type of files that windows alerts you about?  For me, this only occurs with PDF files shortly after I move/copy them.

Answer (score 151):

I experienced the same issues as Harry Johnston has mentioned. `rmdir /s /q` would complain that a directory was not empty even though `/s` is meant to do the emptying for you! I think it's a bug in Windows, personally.

My workaround is to `del` everything in the directory before deleting the directory itself:

```
del /f /s /q mydir 1>nul
rmdir /s /q mydir
```

(The `1>nul` hides the standard output of `del` because otherwise, it lists every single file it deletes.)

Comment: I ran into a scenario where some sub directories within `mydir` produced the same "not empty" error. So I had to `cd` into `mydir` and perform the `del` on the files in each of those directories as well. Ultimately it worked, but if I'd have had to repeat the process a third time at another sublevel, I'd have felt pretty defeated.

Comment: @gfullam As far as I recall, my method should work on recursive subdirectories too, for any depth. That's what `del /s` does.

Comment: Using explorer (probably also mkdir => NO!), adding a folder (and changing the name) finish the job of removal using only the `rd /s /q mydir` command.

Comment: @RajnishCoder Living with Windows is basically a world of workarounds. This particular issue is nothing compared to other problems with Windows 10!

Comment: I had this problem when a hidden directory or file was in the directory that I tried to delete. @BoffinBrain's solution solved that.

Comment: This might ask for a confirmation input too, in my case I had to prepend `echo y|` to the command for it to get accepted. Looking like this: `echo y| rmdir /s /q mydir`

Answer (score 63):

I'm familiar with this problem.  The simplest workaround is to conditionally repeat the operation.  I've never seen it fail twice in a row - unless there actually is an open file or a permissions issue, obviously!

```
rd /s /q c:\deleteme
if exist c:\deleteme rd /s /q c:\deleteme
```

Comment: holy molly, this make no sense yet it worked. What the #!%#@! microsoft

Comment: `IF EXIST` hides `Access is denied` and other situations. I have added somthing like `DIR c:\deleteme` and erros checking before everything.

Comment: Having windows explorer open in a subdirectory or otherwise browsing causes this to fail twice in a row.   So make sure you ask it a third time (which actually worked)

Comment: Actually it _has_ occurred twice in a row for me without anything open or a permissions issue.  My record is seven times.  Recommend @BoffinbraiN's approach.

Comment: I ran only the first command. Then right-clicked the folder > Properties > Uncheck 'Read-only' attribute > Apply. Viola!, the folder finally disappeared.

Comment: I saw it failing twice :( However, adding it a 3rd time and it's working as a charm :D

Answer (score 36):

enter the Command Prompt as Admin and run

```
rmdir /s <FOLDER>
```

Comment: This is no different to what the OP was doing.

Answer (score 34):

I just encountered the same problem and it had to do with some files being lost or corrupted. To correct the issue, just run check disk:

```
chkdsk /F e:
```

This can be run from the search windows box or from a cmd prompt. The `/F` fixes any issues it finds, like recovering the files. Once this finishes running, you can delete the files and folders like normal.

Comment: Perfect, I was trying since half hour

Comment: This found some hidden files in my folder, which then I was able to delete. Really nasty 

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem, tried to delete an empty folder via windows explorer. Showed me the not empty error, so I thought I try it via admin cmd, but none of the answers here helped.

**After I moved a file into the empty folder. I was able to delete the non empty folder**

Comment: Please write it in comment.

Comment: Interesting.  Probably not relevant to the OPs scenario, though.

Comment: Holy moly, this was literally the only think that worked of all these other solutions!

Answer (score 6):

Im my case i just moved the folder to root directory like so.

```
move <source directory> c:\
```

And then ran the command to remove the directory

```
rmdir c:\<moved directory> /s /q
```

Comment: `rmdir c:\<moved directory> /s /q` is the correct answer

Comment: It is NOT the correct answer. deleting a folder in the root can cause the same messages : folder is not empty.

Comment: I know this is an old thread. Just wanted to say this worked for me ...

Answer (score 6):

As @gfullam stated in a comment to @BoffinbraiN's answer, the `<dir>` you are deleting itself might not be the one which contains files: there might be subdirectories in `<dir>` that get a "The directory is not empty" message and the only solution then would be to recursively iterate over the directories, manually deleting all their containing files... I ended up deciding to use a port of `rm` from UNIX. `rm.exe` comes with Git Bash, MinGW, Cygwin, GnuWin32 and others. You just need to have its parent directory in your PATH and then execute as you would in a UNIX system.

Batch script example:

```
set PATH=C:\cygwin64\bin;%PATH%
rm -rf "C:\<dir>"
```

Answer (score 3):

I had "C:\Users\User Name\OneDrive\Fonts", which was mklink'ed ( /D ) to "C:\Windows\Fonts", and I got the same problem. In my case

> cd "C:\Users\User Name\OneDrive"
>
> rd /s Fonts
>
> Y (to confirm the action)

helped me. I hope, that it helps you too ;D

Comment: Add /q to avoid the need for confirmation when running a batch.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is the following. I appears like the RMDir command will issue “The directory is not empty” nearly all the time...

```
:Cleanup_Temporary_Files_and_Folders

Erase /F /S /Q C:\MyDir

RMDir /S /Q C:\MyDir
If  Exist  C:\MyDir  GoTo Cleanup_Temporary_Files_and_Folders
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason `rd /s` refuses to delete certain files is most likely due to READONLY file attributes on files in the directory.

The proper way to fix this, is to make sure you reset the attributes on all files first:

```sh
attrib -r %directory% /s /d
rd /s %directory%
```

There could be others such as hidden or system files, so if you want to play it safe:

```sh
attrib -h -r -s %directory% /s /d
rd /s %directory%
```

Answer (score 2):

one liner:

`if exist folder rmdir /Q /S folder`

I'm using this in a NPM script like so (Javascript) :

```json
//package.json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel --no-cache",
    "clean": "if exist dist rmdir /Q /S dist",
    "deploy": "npm run clean && parcel build --no-source-maps && firebase deploy"
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

Open CMD as administrator

```
chkdsk c: /F /R
```

- Press the “Y” key if asked to check your disk the next time your system restarts.

Restart the machine. After that just delete the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Windows sometimes is "broken by design", so you need to create an empty folder, and then mirror the "broken folder" with an "empty folder" with backup mode.

```
robocopy - cmd copy utility

/copyall - copies everything
/mir deletes item if there is no such item in source a.k.a mirrors source with
destination
/b works around premissions shenanigans
```

Create en empty dir like this:

```
mkdir empty
```

overwrite broken folder with empty like this:

```
robocopy /copyall /mir /b empty broken
```

and then delete that folder

```
rd broken /s
rd empty /s
```

If this does not help, try restarting in "recovery mode with command prompt" by holding shift when clicking restart and trying to run these command again in recovery mode

Comment: Yes, I think Robocopy would work in the OPs scenario, because it automatically retries failed operations.  You probably want to specify `/W:0` to avoid unnecessary delays.  You might not want `/b` because that requires administrative privileges.  Recovery mode isn't relevant to this question, because we're talking about a batch script, not someone manually trying to remove a directory.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following possible causes:

1. there are files or subdirectories which need higher permissions
2. there are files in use, not only by WSearch, but maybe by your virus scanner or anything else

For 1.) you can try `runas /user:Administrator` in order to get higher privileges or start the batch file as administrator via context menu. If that doesn't help, maybe even the administrator doesn't have the rights. Then you need to take over the ownership of the directory.

For 2.) download [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), click `Find/Find handle or DLL...` or press <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd>, type the name of the directory and find out who uses it. Close the application which uses the directory, if possible.

Comment: The machines have the admin account disabled. I am in the admin group but I am no aware of an administrator password. Any other suggestions to get around the permission issue? Someone mentioned calling another program from batch (like vba).

Comment: @Mayhem: getting around permissions is quite hard... We would probably need an exploit for a bug in Windows to do that without a password.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Harry Johnston's answer, I loop until it works.

```
set dirPath=C:\temp\mytest
:removedir
if exist "%dirPath%" (
    rd /s /q "%dirPath%" 
    goto removedir
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Force delete the directory (if exists)

**Delete.bat**

```bash
set output_path="C:\Temp\MyFolder"
    
if exist %output_path% (
   echo Deleting %output_path%
   attrib -r /s /d %output_path%
   rd /s /q %output_path%
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this before my making sure there wasn't extra whitespace in the name of the directory I was deleting. This is more of a concern when I had the directory name contained within a variable that I was passing to `RD`. If you're specifying your directly in quotes then this isn't helpful, but I hope that someone like me comes along with the same problem and sees this. `RD /S /Q` can work, as I noticed the issue started happening when I changed something in my batch script.