# no reliable recursive directory delete possible?

Tags: java, windows

The symptoms are simple: Windows refuses to delete a directory because it thinks that its contents are still there -- although the recursive delete just deleted them. So my first guess is that there is a flush/sync or similar missing on the parent directory after deleting its contents and before deleting it.

I tried commons-io version 2.5 FileUtils.deleteDirectory and FileUtils.cleanDirectory functions as well as my own simplified test:

```
@Test
public void testMySimpleDelete() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    File dir = TEST_DIR;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        dir = new File(dir, Integer.toString(i));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        LOG.info(""+i);
        assertTrue("loop #" + i, dir.mkdirs());
        mySimpleDelete(Paths.get(TEST_DIR.getAbsolutePath()));
        assertFalse(TEST_DIR.exists());
    }
}

private void mySimpleDelete(Path file) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Files.walkFileTree(file, new FileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
            //LOG.info(dir.toString());
            Files.delete(dir);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
}
```

All show the same results/symptoms.

If you want to verify this behavior for yourself (on Windows only! Linux does not lock anything at all and behaves in a way more lenient way), simply check out https://github.com/jjYBdx4IL/java-evaluation and run "mvn test -Dtest=org.apache.commons.io.FileUtilsTest".

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/22948189/886887

Answer (score 1):

The problem was TortoiseGIT *again*. Last time it was so dumb and did not configure its packaged git.exe and used the one from my cygwin installation, which caused problems and wasted my time.

Now, in this case, the status cache, that is used to display status icons within Windows explorer, even scans git-ignored build and test directories, thereby locking stuff in there... omg. So bad.

Solution:

```
TortoiseGIT -> Settings -> Icon Overlays -> Status Cache set to None
```