# Can't remove node_modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, package.json

I recently made a personal project using this [Dapp University Marketplace](https://github.com/dappuniversity/nft_marketplace) with this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bjVWclBD_s&t=2733s&ab_channel=DappUniversity).

After doing the project I now have many folders with node_modules in it (i have many folders because i keep making mistakes and wanted to restart in `npm install`). So, now I want to remove the folders but I can't.

I already tried:

- Deleting directly from file explorer
- Deleting from VS code
- Using `npx rimraf node_modules` (i'll just get `errno: -4094, code: 'UNKNOWN', syscall: 'scandir',`)
- Using npkill (i would just get `[ERROR]` message)
- Using `rmdir /s /q node_modules`( i would get
  `node_modules\@babel\COMPAT~1 - The directory is not empty. node_modules\HANDLE~1\lib - The directory is not empty. node_modules\TRUE-C~1\test\fixture - The directory is not empty. node_modules\xhr\VSCODE~1 - The directory is not empty.`)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948189/how-to-solve-the-directory-is-not-empty-error-when-running-rmdir-command-in-a

Comment: You can use a shell like Git Bash (you may have it installed already) and run `rm -rf node_modules`.